# How to solve a generalised linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression

Let's say I have a generalised linear (system of) equations. What I mean by that is, say I have something like:

$$ \sum_i A_i X B_i = C $$

Where $A_i$ and $B_i$ are matrices and the equation is to be solved for $X$. Is there a closed-form solution (or failing that, least-squares solution)? As an example, let's take the equation $A_1XB_1 + 2aIXI + IXB_3 = C$. The identity matrices are added to be compatible with the notation I defined above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the [vectorisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) and [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) operations, we can re-write the equation as:

$$
  \sum_i (B_i^T \otimes A_i)\mathbf{vec}(X)=\mathbf{vec}(C)
$$

from which we can get the (exact or least-squares) solution to this problem using:

$$
  \mathbf{vec}(X)=\left( \sum_i (B_i^T \otimes A_i) \right)^\dagger \mathbf{vec}(C)
$$

and performing the inverse-vectorise operation. Here $M^\dagger$ denotes the [Moore-Penrose psuedoinverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse) of the matrix $M$.